# Sending SPARQL update query to Graphdb from Angular

Tags: angular, curl, insert, sparql, graphdb

I am trying to send an UPDATE (insert) to a Graphdb instance, starting from an ANGULAR web-application (typescript). Therefore i would need to create a HTTP GET request but I cannot work out how to correctly format that http request inside the ANGULAR application. Most tutorials online work with .JSON files to get/post data, not with RDF graphs.

I was hoping to do this through 'curl' and somehow start a curl-command from within angular, but i cannot even get the curl command to work inside my own console. I have followed this [Guide](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/quick-start-guide.html#query-data-programmatically) and sifted through stackoverflow answers until i came to the following command for SPARQL UPDATE for graphDB:

```
curl -G -H "Accept:application/x-trig" 
-d update=INSERT+DATA+%7B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample%2F3aan%3E+dc%3Atitle+%22pullnaam%22%7D+
http://localhost:7200/repositories/myrepository/statements
```

When i execute this command, the console returns all resources/nodes inside the graph, but doesn't actually execute the Update inside the curl command.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I apologise in advance if I've forgotten to add something crucial. I'm testing out some more variations on the curl command and hope to edit this question soon.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: working curl command is:

```
curl -X POST -G -H "Accept:application/x-trig" -d
update=INSERT+DATA+%7B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample%2F4aan%3E+dc%3Atitle+%22pullnaam%22%7D+ 
http://localhost:7200/repositories/myrepository/statements
```

Edit: working POST command inside typescript/angular is:

```
function(event){
const body = "update=INSERT+DATA+%7B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample%2Ftesteroo%3E+dc%3Atitle+%22pullnaam%22%7D+";
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/x-trig').set('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
let options = { headers:HttpHeaders};
var url = "http://128.199.58.129:7200/repositories/repo/statements";
return this.http.post(url,body,{headers:headers}).toPromise().then(function(response) { console.log(response.toString())});
}
```

Comment: I thought you have to use a POST request for SPARQL Update or not? See the [SPARQL specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/#update-operation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting back statements because you are doing a GET request against the `/statements` resource. A SPARQL update is a POST request. You need to add `-X POST` to your curl request.

Comment: Thanks it's indeed as simple as that. I have tried using the POST command as written inside the graphDB guide, which didn't work. The working curl command is now: 


curl -X POST -G -H "Accept:application/x-trig" -d update=INSERT+DATA+%7B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample%2F4aan%3E+dc%3Atitle+%22pullnaam%22%7D+ http://localhost:7200/repositories/myrepository/statements


Now i need to simply find a way to make such a POST command starting from angular, but i'm sure i can find that on my own. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndrewMalcolm isn't it already part of the `Http` class? There should be a method `Http.post()`

Comment: @AKSW yes, but i need to format that command as well. This is what i have right now, but it doesn't seem to be working:  

`var body= 
 "update=INSERT+DATA+%7B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample%2F6aan%3E+dc%3Atitle+%22pullnaam%22%7D+";  
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/x-trig');  


    let options = { headers:HttpHeaders};  

    var url = "http://localhost:7200/repositories/DBtestclean/statements";  

    this.http.post(url,body,{headers});`

Comment: Hm, why do you use this Accept MIME type? This is just for GET requests. Don't copy and paste things, try to understand the concept and start from scratch. Did you read the [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/#update-operation) I referred to earlier? Check everything there, especially the request content type. It's clearly not Trig

Comment: @AKSW I got it to work  thanks to those docs and browsing overflow, thanks again. just needed a bit longer to understand some things because i have no programming background. The 'accept :x-trig' header was necessary though, probably a GraphDB thing. (the working typescript can be found in the question)

Comment: @AndrewMalcolm Good to hear. Yes, the beginning can always be a bit difficult.

Comment: @AndrewMalcolm Regarding the content type. I still don't think that this is correct. The specs say *"Content-Type: specifies the mediatype of a POST request body. Possible values are “application/x-www-form-urlencoded” (for a SPARQL query or update encoded as a form parameter), “application/sparql-query” (for an unencoded SPARQL query string) or “application/sparql-update” (for an unencoded SPARQL update string)."*